# If every subset of X is open then there are no limit points in X

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then if every subset in $X$ is open there are no limit points in $X$.

This is probably a very simple question, but I just can't seem to get anywhere with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* $x$ is a limit point if every open neighborhood of $x$ also contains an element of $X$ which is not $x$. However, $\{x\}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel pretty stupid now!

Comment: @Tim2000 Nonsense! These are techniques you build with practice. Math is always 20/20 in hindsight..

Comment: @Tom: a lot of the time, yes. Always? I'm not so sure... There are quite a few proofs I've seen which are just as hideous and incomprehensible in hindsight as they are at first glance.

Comment: @tomasz fair enough... I suppose math is always 20/20 in hindsight for sufficiently small values of always... where we make the following definition: $\epsilon$ is a sufficiently small value of always iff $\epsilon$ belongs to the set of "sometimes"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a limit point $x$. Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ belonging to the set such that $x_n\rightarrow x$. Then the set conatining all the $x_n$'s for all $n$, and $x$ is a closed set, although it is definitely a subset of the set in question. Hence contradiction.